# Tyre size and Turbo Trainers

Tags: tire, trainer

Are there any advantages in having a 700x25 tyre over a 700x23 when using a cycle trainer?

If you are "training", resistance is surely not a huge deal breaker. I assume cycle trainer tyres last a fair amount of time.

If it is just a way of transferring energy to a roller, I assume a bigger tyre will do that more efficiently.

Comment: There a special tyres for turbo trainers. They are harder and tougher. Don't use them on the road!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bigger tire will give you slightly higher gearing due to the higher diameter. You should get a trainer specific tire, as the compounds are harder to prevent overheating/excessive tire wear. Your tire isn't slipping against the roller on the trainer in either case, so the power transfer argument is relatively moot (theres rolling resistance and what not, but its not something you should be worrying about on a trainer...).

The reason why you'd get a 700x25 tire over a 700x23 tire would be that if your rim was wider, it may support a 700x25 tire [better](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html).  This is why some trainer tires are produced in 700x23 and 700x32 (e.g. Continental Hometrainer-- the larger size will fit some 29ers barely, which have wider rims). Most road racing bikes are designed for 23's so its easiest to ship 23's, which most trainer tires are, for road bikes. Also, there exist frames which will rub with a 25 but not a 23.

The TL;DR version: pick whichever one you want, provided your frame doesn't rub.

Also, I didn't find anyone actually producing a trainer tire for 700x25 -- there are training tires for 700x25 but they're for the road, not for the trainer.

Comment: Looking back at my shopping search results, and yeah, it looks like people are pushing slicks as trainer tyres. I almost feel like I should close or amend the question.

Comment: A trainer tire is a specific type of tire made for use specifically on a trainer. Regular tires (e.g. slicks made for the road) will wear down quickly on a trainer.

Comment: Thank you Batman. Did you know there is a place called Batman in Turkey near the border with Syria?